# How to remove Soap namespace associated with attribute

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have to remove the soap name space associated with ConfigR(attribute).

Inside XSLT I am using XSL Copy and hence exclude prefix is not working.

I have tried below, but not working.Please can anyone suggest.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
     <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:template>
       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input -

```
              <soapenv:Envelope 
           xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <soapenv:Body>
      <ConfigR>
        Inside I have some more input.
      </ConfigR>
        </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>   




     Now in Output I am getting:
         <ConfigR xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace you existing template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with following:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You can find it [here](http://xsltransform.net/asnmyJ)

Comment: Thanks for looking into.Getting below error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: urn:from-string; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: Okay. In that case you can try the above implementation.